# Watch File Changes on Service Fabric Web App

Tags: asp.net, angular, azure-service-fabric

We have a web app published using Service Fabric App. My problem is I cannot immediately see my changes in client-side. I need to run "npm run build" and publish the Service Fabric again which takes more than 10 minutes.

Is there a way or a script that I can add so I can see my changes on the running web app (just refreshing the app will reflect it, like a normal web app not running on service fabric)?

Comment: Is what you're asking, "How can I immediately see changes when developing against a production site hosted in service fabric?".

Comment: My service fabric is configured only on my local machine. I've already tried the instructions here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/04/17/speed-up-service-fabric-development-with-the-new-refresh-application-debug-mode-2/

But I'm always getting "your app has entered a break state" message.

Comment: Hello! were you able to find a solution for this? I would also like to let my local changes be deployed to SF web app automatically.